# wordpress user management, how to assign specific page to each user?

Tags: wordpress

I want to create pages in WordPress, which should show to a specific user only not for specific role.

if a page is created for a specific user like "john". it should be viewed by only john, no other users could not see that page.

My Questions are:

1. How to create a page for a specific user? (from admin).
   Note: while creating page we should assign that page to specific user like "john".
2. Is there any plugins for this?

Is there any way to do this.

-Srikanth.

Comment: It surely has a way to do it. What I do when a need "private" pages is in the beginning of the page test a user ID. You could make a plugin for that!

Answer (score 3):

I know that it is a bit late but still want to answer in case you need. Try to use http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-specific-content/    plugin. You can customize your pages.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea:

Why not make a page template for that page? get current user id in the template then show the details depends on the user id? You can check is_user_logged_in() and pull all contents under the if statement and under the else statement you can redirect the user to the login page or just show the message to logged in.

Let me know if everything is clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with ease using nav menu plugin and roles creator plugin.you can create roles with names of your clients and show menu items of user pages to specific roles/person